# provide useful message when cmake <3.19 is used with --preset flag

Tags: cmake, error-handling, cmake-presets

I'm trying to return a useful error message when `cmake < 3.19` is used by the user to compile a project that has presets. The problem is that, for `cmake`s older than `3.19` the flag `--preset` is meaningless and, i believe, it is completely ignored.

Here is an example:

```
cmake --preset ValidPreset
> CMake Error: The source directory "/absolute/path/ValidPreset" does not exist.
```

which is misleading at best and has nothing to do with the version of `cmake`. Is there any way to signal this to the users?

Putting

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
```

in the `CMakeLists.txt` is useless as the file is not even open, the same goes for something like:

```
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 19,
    "patch": 0
  },
```

in the `CMakePresets.json` as earlier version of `cmake` have no idea what that file is.

Is there an hack or workaround to signal the wrong version to the users?

Answer (score 1):

You may create for every preset a directory with the same name, where put the `CMakeLists.txt` file. That file would just emit an error message. E.g.

```
message(FATAL_ERROR "You use CMake of version ${CMAKE_VERSION}, but minimum required is 3.19. After upgrading CMake remove the file '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeCache.txt' and try again")
```

So, instead of emitting a message about non-existence directory `<...>/ValidPreset` CMake will find `CMakeLists.txt` in that directory and execute it.

Downside of this approach is that CMake will organize a source directory of your project as a **build** one, so every further attempt to build your project will silently(!) use the same build directory, until a user removes at least `CMakeCache.txt` file from it.

---

I have seen a project which contains `CMakeLists.txt` in some of its subdirectories, which was a legacy way for run CMake. In that project "fake" `CMakeLists.txt` just emits a warning, but then calls root `CMakeLists.txt`.

But in your case I don't find useful for fake `CMakeLists.txt` to attempt to perform a regular build. The main reason is that root directory will be used as a build one, which is definitely not desired neither by you (as the project developer) nor by a user. So it is better to explicitly ask user to invoke `cmake` without `--preset` option.